# How to check if a char is in a .txt file?

Tags: c

In my program I am supposed to make a rush hour game in C. I am importing the board shown from a text file.

After than I ask the user for input, which is supposed to be the char on the board he wants to move.

My question is when the user picks the char, how can I check if the char he picked exists in the board.txt file, because if it doesn't, I need to ask the user to pick a new character.

This is how the input section of the code looks so far:

```
char Direction[1];
char Vehicle[1];
int intInput =0;

// get the char input for the type of vehicle
printf("Please enter which vehicle you would like to move:\n");
scanf("%s", &Vehicle);
//THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO CHECK IF THE CHAR PICKED EXISTS IN board.txt 
printf(" This is the input: %s\n", Vehicle);

//get the char input for the direction you want to move
printf("Please choose if you want to move right(R) or left(L):\n");
scanf("%s", &Direction);

if(Direction != "r"||"l"){
    printf("Please choose a valid direction(R=Right L=Left):\n");
    scanf("%s", &Direction);
}
else{
    printf("Your move was %s\n", Direction);
}
//get the int input
printf("Enter how far you would like to move:");
scanf("%d", &intInput);

if(intInput<0){
    printf("Please enter a positive integer:");
    scanf("%d", &intInput);
}
else{
    printf("The inpuy is %d", intInput);
}
```

Comment: You need to read your textbook/course/whatever again `Direction != "r"||"l"` doesn't do what you think it does... The answer to the question is as you read board.txt you need to "remember" what was in it so you can use it later...

Comment: If you know the size of the board beforehand, then you can store it in a buffer (and if you're trying to manipulate the same board multiple times, then better keep it in that buffer instead of reading the file multiple times). Then search for the appropriate character in that buffer, and, in addition to the previous comment, convert your if statements into while loops.

Comment: How does you store the imported board information?

Comment: Two extra tips:

1. the `char Direction[1]; char Vehicle[1];` could just be `char` rather than `char [1]`

2. the `if(Direction != "r"||"l")`, you should at least convert the `Direction` to small case to compare.

Answer (score 0):

`how I check if the char he picked exists in the board.txt`

The best method is to read the data per line into a buffer to read use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

And find `char` in that buffer. To find use [strchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)

following code illustrate what i mean

```
FILE *  fp;
fp= fopen("board.txt", "r");
char    buffer[256];

if (!fp)
{
    printf("error");
    return;
}
while (fgets(buffer, 256, fp))
{
   char *ptr = strchr(str, Direction);
    if(ptr)
       printf("found\n");   
    else
      printf("Not found\n");    
} 
fclose(fp);
```